# Error a la hora de exportar un (.rpt) a (.pdf) en .NET

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

> ```
> Dim rutaDB As String = "C:\prueba\Crystal\bdfabrica.mdb"
> Dim informe As String = "C:\prueba\LisVolOperCliDetalle.rpt"
> Dim informePDF As String = "C:\prueba\LisVolOperCliDetalle.pdf"
> ```

```
Public Sub imprimirInforme()

            fechaInicio = CDate("10/10/2016")
            fechaFin = CDate("10/10/2017")
            diaInicio = (fechaInicio).Day
            diaFinal = (fechaFin).Day
            mesInicio = (fechaInicio).Month
            mesFinal = (fechaFin).Month
            annoInicio = (fechaInicio).Year
            annoFinal = (fechaFin).Year

            Try
            With informeRpt
                .Database.Tables(0).Location = rutaDB
                .RecordSelectionFormula = "{RegIVARe.Fecha_Factura} in Date(" & annoInicio & "," & mesInicio & "," & diaInicio & ") to Date(" & annoFinal & "," & mesFinal & "," & diaFinal & ") AND " & "{RegIVARe.Cod_Cliente} = " & codCliente & ""
            End With


            parFecInicio.Name = "fechaInicio"
            fInicio.Value = fechaInicio
            parFecInicio.CurrentValues.Add(fInicio)
            parametros.Add(parFecInicio)


            parFecFinal.Name = "fechaFinal"
            fFinal.Value = fechaInicio
            parFecFinal.CurrentValues.Add(fFinal)
            parametros.Add(parFecFinal)

            cr.ReportSource = informeRpt
            cr.DisplayGroupTree = False
            cr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            cr.ParameterFieldInfo = parametros

            Dim frmReporte As New Form
            With frmReporte
                .Controls.Add(cr)
                .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            End With

            frmReporte.Show()
            Thread.Sleep(2000)
        informeRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, informePDF)

        Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

El código me genera bien el reporte, pero a la hora de crear el `pdf` me da un error:

> ```
> en esta linea 
> informeRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, informePDF)
> ```

Este es el error en `tiempo de ejecución`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es como si estuviese buscando el `.rpt` en la carpeta temporal.

Pero a la hora de exportar, si me está cogiendo bien la ruta donde se encuentra mi `.pdf`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Alguien sabe donde puede estar el problema ??**

**Gracias**

Answer (score 0):

Hola quizas podrias hacerlo de una manera mas facil. En ocasiones cuando tienes el reporte visualizado tienes la opciones de elegir una impresora en una de estas impresoras podrias elegir la que esta relacionada al programa pdf y asi te lo exporta a pdf, en mi caso yo uso Foxit Reader y este me coloca una impresora pdf printer cada programa lector de pdf te genera una impresora, podrias usar ese medio y facilitar el trabajo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta; se que existe esa función, pero quiero hacerlo a través de un botón, ya que es mas fácil para el usuario generar el pdf directamente.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno si lo que deseas es usar un boton podrias hacer algo asi:

```
Public Shared Function ExportToPDF(rpt As ReportDocument, NombreArchivo As String) As String
Dim vFileName As String = Nothing
Dim diskOpts As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()

Try
    rpt.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
    rpt.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat

            'Este es la ruta donde se guardara tu archivo.'
    vFileName = "c:\Reporte\" & NombreArchivo
    If File.Exists(vFileName) Then
        File.Delete(vFileName)
    End If
    diskOpts.DiskFileName = vFileName
    rpt.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = diskOpts
    rpt.Export()
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
End Try

Return vFileName
End Function
```

Y luego llamarlo al botón:

```
Private Sub btnReporte_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim _reporte As ReportePersonal = Reporte.ObtenerReportePersonal()
Dim frm As New frmReportePersonal(_reporte)
frm.Show()

Utilidades.ExportToPDF(_reporte, "rptPersonal.pdf")

End Sub
```

Analizalo y adaptalo.
Saludos